# How to reinitialize the LoggingSystem in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boots LoggingSystem abstraction has no reload/reinitialize method.
Is there another way of reinitializing the LoggingSystem (regardless of the underlying implementation)?

What I want to achieve:
Registering a SIGHUP-signalhandler triggering a LoggigSystem-reinit so that the log-filhandles are closed and reopend so logrotate can rotate the logfiles.

Comment: There's a `protected` `reinitialise` method on `AbstractLoggingSystem`. If that method's behaviour meets your requirements we could consider making it `public`

Comment: I tried to make the reinitialize() public, unfortunately that's not so easy.
For example the LogbackLoggingSystem only loads the config from the default location, but not from the specified one...

Comment: I try to do a cleanUp() and a full initilization....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using logback, you can call the method reset from the class LoggerContext.

For example, in a JUnit5 test:

```
@BeforeAll
static void init() {
  final var loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
  loggerContext.reset();
}
```